# Why are the li tags not inheriting parent font?

Tags: html, css

I am nearly done with this webpage and have some list items, but the li tags aren't inheriting the parent font. I have tried multiple ways to resolve it including using the ul and li tags to add inherit styling, but still no change. I've posted the code below. Thanks as always!

```css
.section-plans {
    background-color: #f4f4f4;
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
}

.plan-box {
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 90%;
    margin-left: 5%;
}

.plan-box div {
    padding: 15px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e8e8e8;
}

.residential {
    font-size: 300%;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="col span 1-of-3">
  <div class="plan-box">
    <div>
      <h3>Commercial</h3>
      <p class="residential"></p>
      <ul>
        <li><i class="far fa-check-circle">Clean & Disinfect</i></li>
        <li><i class="far fa-check-circle">Emptry trash bins</i></li>
        <li><i class="far fa-check-circle">Sweep & mop floor</i></li>
        <li><i class="far fa-check-circle">Vaccum carpets & upholstry</i></li>
        <li><i class="far fa-check-circle">Thoroughly wipe down handles & doors</i></li>
        <li><i class="far fa-check-circle">Smudge free windown wipedown</i></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <div>
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-full">Sign up now</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Because the contents is inside the `i` tag, the `i` tag has the `fa` class which is applying the font-awsome font.

Comment: So when I removed the far and fa classes the font still does not change. Is there another way I could include the icon from font awesome without the text inheriting the font?

Comment: Yes, move the contents outside the `i` tags, and have it inside a `span` or similar, making sure both elements are `inline`. Changing the font-family on the `i` is the other alternative, however you'd be breaking the font-awesome. Or you could nest another tag (a span perhaps) inside the `i` tag and set styles on that directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this because your `i` tag , you can fix it with add this line to your css

```
ul li i {
        font-style: normal;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Need to change in **i** tag close it before li text start instead of close end of the li text. Run code snippet

```js
.section-plans {
    background-color: #f4f4f4;
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
}

.plan-box {
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 90%;
    margin-left: 5%;
}

.plan-box div {
    padding: 15px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e8e8e8;
}

.residential {
    font-size: 300%;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js"></script>
<div class="col span 1-of-3">
  <div class="plan-box">
    <div>
      <h3>Commercial</h3>
      <p class="residential"></p>
      <ul>
        <li><i class="far fa-check-circle"></i> Clean & Disinfect</li>
        <li><i class="far fa-check-circle"></i> Emptry trash bins </li>
        <li><i class="far fa-check-circle"></i> Sweep & mop floor </li>
        <li><i class="far fa-check-circle"></i> Vaccum carpets & upholstry </li>
        <li><i class="far fa-check-circle"></i> Thoroughly wipe down handles & doors </li>
        <li><i class="far fa-check-circle"></i> Smudge free windown wipedown </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <div>
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-full">Sign up now</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks you guys I really appreciate it!